# Sitecore 7 Search - Best practice search not using search.ashx

Tags: search, lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

This post suggests that we should not use the search.ashx to do a search in Sitecore 7:
[Sitecore 7 Search - Search.ashx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835055/sitecore-7-search-search-ashx?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, the answer is not correct since you cannot use the Item Web API to search, it provides CRUD access but not search out of the box:

[How to Access Sitecore Lucene Search through the Item Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051009/how-to-access-sitecore-lucene-search-through-the-item-web-api)

So, we are left with a) rolling our own search wrapper around the .net sitecore search api's and hook into the Item Web API pipelines or b) bind to the internal Sitecore search service and hope it does not change (at least not too often).  Personally, I think option b is more fragile but gets me going faster.  Option a is more involved yet would put me more in control of the search interface I am consuming.  However, if we step back, it seems Sitecore should have a clear best practice or recommendation on conducting searches in Sitecore 7 through a web service of some sort.  If you know the recommendation or have a option c please reply.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best it to go with option a)

You just have to do the following:

1. Implement your processor. You need to parse the luceneQuery and then, you can use the PredicateBuilder or the LinqHelper to build your query.

You can find more information on the PredicateBuilder [in this blog post](http://www.sitecore.net/Learn/Blogs/Technical-Blogs/Sitecore-7-Development-Team/Posts/2013/05/Sitecore-7-Predicate-Builder.aspx)

2. Inside the itemWebApiRequest pipeline, add a new parameter to `<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.CheckParameters, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" >`. Something like this: `<name desc="item id15">luceneQuery</name>`.
3. Hook your processor after `<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.Request.ResolveItems, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" />`

That's it. I hope it helps.